# Different WP Query dependent on the Category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a page which lists different courses depending on the category. The normal query works:

```
$args=array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'category_name' => 'raid'
        );

      //$courses_query = null;
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but the above code means creating another template each time a new category is added, which means duplicating the code and changing one part of the page. The page would be domainname.com/courses/sdi-courses, and each time the url changing for each category.

```
'category_name' => 'sdi'// this will change to raid, padi etc.
```

This is the code I am using.

```
<?php

  // The Query
        if (is_category('sdi-courses')) { // page slug
            $args=array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category_name' => 'sdi' // slug of category
          );
        } else (is_category('raid-courses')) {
            $args=array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category_name' => 'raid'
          );
        } 

       $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

He will only have a few of these, but there must be a better way of doing it. I tried with the above code but it does not work. I imagine it is something to do with what it returns from the if statement once it has got the correct information for $args=array.

Any help would be great, I do not do much WP or PHP, so I am struggling with this one.

Comment: Can you say in which file are you querying the loop? like single.php or front-page.php. I need the file name to know how the category is decided.

Comment: Yes, please tell us what file this code is from - it does make a difference!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $cat = get_the_category();
 $args=array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'category_name' => $cat,
);

//$courses_query = null;
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The current category name will be populated in the $cat variable.

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi, I am afraid that did not work.It showed all of the post's.Please see the screenshot attached, just to make sure I have done the right thing regarding the category naming.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4nbczd58leyyjf/Screenshot%202017-08-26%2011.51.46.png?dl=0

Comment: What output you require?

Comment: I want a conditional statement so it uses this code when the page is 'sdi-courses' - domain/courses/sdi-courses

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
     'category_name' => 'sdi'

then when the page is raid-courses - domain/courses/raid-courses , it uses

 'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
     'category_name' => 'raid'

I do not mind adding lots of conditional statements into the code, as there are only about 5 different categories to display. Just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific post category by using current post ID.

Please check the below code:

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID ); // You will get category as array

echo '<pre>';print_r($postcat) // print array to check what will you getting.
$postcat[0]->term_id  // you will get ID of the category.
$postcat[0]->name //  you will get name of the category.
```

Hope, this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this in some page then you can always make a function and pass a parameter as category name and use that in different page

```
 function abc($cat) {
 $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'category_name' => $cat
    );

  //$courses_query = null;
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```